# How to check for broken bindings due to mesh editing after binding a mesh deform modifier in Blender Python?

Tags: python, modifiers

I have about 300 objects in my scene and I want to bind them all to one deformer object via the Mesh Deform modifier to create a cartoonish perspective distortion.

To accomplish this, I have written the following python script:

```py
import bpy

# Convenience Variables : Blender Python console-style shorthand.
D = bpy.data 
C = bpy.context

def add_and_bind_mesh_deform(targets, deformer_name):
    # Iterate through the target objects
    for obj in targets:
        # Check the object type (only MESH or CURVE)
        if obj.type not in ['MESH', 'CURVE']:
            continue
            
        # Add Mesh Deform modifier
        mesh_deform_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="MeshDeform", type='MESH_DEFORM')
        mesh_deform_modifier.object = D.objects[deformer_name]
        
        # Bind the Mesh Deform modifier
        C.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.meshdeform_bind(modifier="MeshDeform")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deformer_name = "Deformer"
    targets = C.selected_objects

    add_and_bind_mesh_deform(targets, deformer_name)
```

However, I need a feedback loop to improve the quality of my scene layout, so I often find myself editing the meshes of objects that are already bound. Each time I do this, I get a warning message that the number of vertices has changed, as shown in the image below.
[image]

So I want to conditionally check if the binding state of the mesh deform modifier is broken, and only perform the binding operation on the problematic objects.

#### So my question is:

How do I check if the Mesh Deform modifier's binding state is broken?

NOTE: States 1 and 2 can be checked via `C.object.modifiers["MeshDeform"].is_bound`. Not that, I want to check state 3.

1. before binding
2. after binding
3. bound, but the connection is broken because the number of vertices has changed.